# Node js Express Send requests to your own app inside your own app

Tags: node.js

Is there a simple way to run request to your app inside it?

What do I mean:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    flag = getStatusFromDB()
    if(flag){
------>  run_app.post("/start")  
}

app.post("/start", (req, res) => {
```

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Just call whatever function does the actual work behind that endpoint directly.

Comment: I already did it. Just have a question that can't answer.

Comment: Already did _what_? If you have some working implementation you're trying to improve on, show it in your question.

Comment: I mean it's not kind of questions like "help me guys I'm stuck".
It's more like "doesn't looks like a good practice but how it's possible to do".

Comment: Pure curiosity doesn't make useful Stack Overflow questions, without the context and constraints of an actual problem it's hard to provide an appropriate solution. The right answer is: don't. Or use literally any HTTP client to make the request if you really want to.

Comment: If you want to make an http request to any host (your own or any remote host), you use an http library to send the request and get the response.  You can use the (somewhat lower level) built-in `http` module using `http.get()` or `http.post()`?  Most people will prefer to use a higher level (easier to use) http request library such as any of them listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  My personal favorite is [got()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), but you can pick the one you like.

Comment: All that said, it's pretty inefficient to make an http request to your own host.  As has already been said, you can just call the underlying code behind the http request without going through the http protocol first.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, without any additional network requests, is to move it to its own function:

```js
const start = (req, res) => { /* ... */ }

app.post("/start", start)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const flag = getStatusFromDB()
    if (flag) {
        start(req, res)
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better would be to have a function that _doesn't_ know about the transport layer that you can call from both controllers. You don't own Express's API, don't use it as your own.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Depends what the business logic inside the function is, really. Seems reasonable enough to use the conventions of the API if it's going to be used directly as an express callback in one case and needs access to the request and response variables. But I agree it wouldn't fit in all cases.

Comment: It really doesn't. Think about it: if your "business layer" is taking Express request and response objects, that's the transportation layer leaking out and you don't actually control your own API. As a clear demonstration: if you're using TypeScript, you now need to import from Express _outside_ the transport layer to type your function. Layer for abstraction, so your business logic isn't full of "request" and "response" and talks about the actual domain.